# How to update the version of the kernel used in rescue mode?

Tags: centos, kernel, rescue

I have an up-to-date version of the kernel in my install, `3.10.0-327.28.3`, as installed by yum update.

When I boot into rescue mode, and run uname -r, the version is very old, 3.10.0.10.something.

Is there a way to install a newer rescue kernel?   I notice with this rescue kernel version, I can't start networking, something about device errors.  I'm assuming it is because this kernel is old compared to what it normally runs.

CentOS 7.2